# Can API calls be restricted to a single domain?

Tags: contentful

I see in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36134591/hiding-contentful-space-id-and-access-token-client-side-javascript-file) that hiding credentials from the front end of a website is not possible, but I was wondering if there was an option to restrict calls to a single domain? To prevent the possibility of another site linking to the same content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Contentful does not restrict requests by domain.

You use your api keys (which should remain a secret) to access your data.

I would highly recommend putting your requests behind a server so that you can keep your keys private.

Here is a tonic example where a node server has the access key set up as an environment variable:

https://tonicdev.com/mrsteele/contentpull

Comment: Thank you. That's the answer I was looking for. Unfortunately, in my particular use case, putting the credentials behind a server is not practical. I was investigating using Contentful in correlation with the SaaS ecommerce platform - Bigcommerce, which only provides front-end access. Setting up an external server is a step I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: Heroku is free: https://www.heroku.com/

You could create a simple man-in-the-middle server and hit your own instance on heroku. Then you would have your credentials secured without worry.